# Can any one tell me which gradient used in right side overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]
I want to make a flyer, i don't understand which gradient is used in this image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's from about to 75% bright grey to RGB=115,75,76 (take it with the color picker), the transition zone is quite narrow, the blending mode=multiply and a little black is sprayed into the top of the layer mask to make the right top corner lighter.

[image]

**ADD:** There's a snippet of the original coat color remaining. It's nearly white. That suggests blending mode multiply to be the easiest to apply, because color X * White = color X in blending math. There's seemingly another answer appeared by member @Westside. Read it, it's more general than this.

Comment: can you send me psd file

Comment: I have already tried this but it's not matching, something is missed, i don't why i'm getting difference..

Comment: @MuhammadMoosa Check thishttps://www.dropbox.com/s/r3l1bjf1z6fnafl/GradientOnCover.psd?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It’s pretty easy to figure out any overlay of this type in photoshop. Using the sample / eye dropper tool, simply sample part of the image with the overlay and a similar part of the image without the overlay and the difference between the two is the colour that you need to apply in that area.

In this case, it’s a gradient of a tint of grey through to a medium dark red.

The other thing that affects the look of the result is the transparency mode. This particular image looks like multiply or hard light, but it’s worth experimenting with different settings for your specific design.

Comment: can you send me psd file of this overlay, i have already tried these things